# Why is this attempt to pass a pointer from C++ to Fortran not working?

Tags: c++, pointers, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I need to pass a dynamic array from c++ to Fortran.  I did a lot of research to put together an example that I thought should work, but it doesn't.  The program should create an array in the c++ program, pass the pointer of that array to the Fortran routine, convert the C pointer to a Fortran pointer, and then print the array on the Fortran side.

My c++ main program:

```
using namespace std;

extern "C" {
   void cinterface(int*,int*);
}

int main()
{
   int carray[]={0,1,2,3,4};
   int carray_siz=5;

   cinterface(&carray_siz,carray);

   return 0;
}
```

My Fortran routine:

```
module fortmod

   use ISO_C_BINDING

   implicit none

contains

   subroutine cinterface(carray_siz,carray_ptr) bind(C)

      implicit none

      integer(c_int), intent(in) :: carray_siz
      type(c_ptr), intent(in) :: carray_ptr

      integer(c_int), pointer :: pfarray(:) => NULL()

      call C_F_POINTER(carray_ptr,pfarray,[carray_siz])

      print *, pfarray

   end subroutine cinterface

end module fortmod
```

I build this as:

```
gfortran -c fortmod.f90
g++ main.cpp fortmod.o -lgfortran
```

But when I run it, instead of printing the array values, it says:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm new to the idea of pointers, so I'm thinking I'm not understanding how they work correctly.  Can you please point out why I'm getting this memory error when I run this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the gfortran manual:

> If a pointer is a dummy-argument of an interoperable procedure, it usually has to be
>   declared using the VALUE attribute. void* matches TYPE(C_PTR), VALUE, while TYPE(C_PTR) alone matches void**.

My Fortran routine was looking for the address of the pointer, not the address to which the pointer is pointing.  So if I modify the c++ side to this:

using namespace std;

```
extern "C" {
   void cinterface(int*,int**);
}

int main()
{
   int carray[]={0,1,2,3,4};
   int carray_siz=5;

   cinterface(&carray_siz,&carray);

   return 0;
}
```

re-build and re-run, I now get:

```
0     1     2     3     4
```

as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Surely you want to pass the array size as int, *not* the address of the size:

```
extern "C" {
    void cinterface(int,int*);
}

cinterface(carray_siz,carray);
```

Comment: But Fortran passes arguments by reference, so I think I actually do want to pass the address, right?

Comment: In that case you want to pass the *address* of the array address (i.e. it's reference as well the `carray_siz` reference)