# Bad value being read from Fortran class variable

Tags: c++, c, api, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I'm trying to make a simple Fortran-C binding program, but I'm stuck at a pretty basic concept - printing value from a member variable.

Despite I set it to the value 5, I'm receiving random numbers back - obviously a memory problem. It seems, that the problem is right at `print_vsize()` method, but I have no idea, what can be wrong here.

I also tried to look at the `instance` in Debug mode and it seems, that some internal structure is being constructed in the class:

[image]

**1) Could you, please, provide any advice about what can be wrong with my code?**

**2) Is it possible to apply the same principle for arrays passed as parameters?**

---

#### main.f90

```
program test
    use iso_c_binding
    use myclassbind

    implicit none

    type(myclass) :: instance


    instance = myclass(5)
    call instance%print_vsize()

end program test
```

#### myClass_c_mod.f90

```
module myclassbind
    use iso_c_binding

    implicit none

    private
    public :: myclass

    type myclass
        private
        type(c_ptr) :: ptr

    contains
        procedure :: print_vsize => print_vsize_impl
    end type

    interface myclass
        module procedure create_myclass
    end interface

    interface

        function create_myclass_c(n) bind(C, name="create_myclass_c")
            use iso_c_binding
            implicit none

            type(c_ptr) :: create_myclass_c
            integer(c_int), value :: n
        end function

        subroutine print_vsize_c(obj) bind(C, name="print_vsize_c")
            use iso_c_binding
            implicit none
            type(c_ptr) :: obj
        end subroutine print_vsize_c
    end interface

contains

    function create_myclass(n)
        implicit none
        type(myclass) :: create_myclass
        integer(c_int), intent(in) :: n
        create_myclass%ptr = create_myclass_c(n)
    end function

    subroutine print_vsize_impl(this)
        implicit none
        class(myclass) :: this
        call print_vsize_c(this%ptr)
    end subroutine print_vsize_impl
end module
```

#### myClass_c.h

```
#ifndef FORTRANBIND_MYCLASS_C_H
#define FORTRANBIND_MYCLASS_C_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
    class myClass;
    typedef myClass MYCLASS;
#else
    typedef struct MYCLASS MYCLASS;
#endif

    MYCLASS* create_myclass_c(int n);
    void print_vsize_c(MYCLASS* obj_ptr);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif //FORTRANBIND_MYCLASS_C_H
```

#### myClass_c.cpp

```
#include <vector>

#include "myClass.h"
#include "myClass_c.h"

MYCLASS* create_myclass_c(int n) {
    return new myClass(n);
}

void print_vsize_c(MYCLASS* obj_ptr) {
    obj_ptr->print_vsize();
}
```

#### myClass.h

```
#ifndef FORTRANBIND_MYCLASS_H
#define FORTRANBIND_MYCLASS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class myClass {
private:
    int n;

public:
    explicit myClass(int n);
    void print_vsize();
};

#endif //FORTRANBIND_MYCLASS_H
```

#### myClass.cpp

```
#include "myClass.h"


myClass::myClass(int n) {
    this->n = n;
}

void myClass::print_vsize() {
    std::cout << this->n << std::endl;
}
```

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.13)
PROJECT(FortranBind C CXX Fortran)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
SET(CMAKE_Fortran_STANDARD 2008)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(FortranBind main.f90)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(FortranBind PUBLIC myClass_c_mod )

ADD_LIBRARY(myClass_c_mod myClass_c_mod.f90 myClass.cpp myClass_c.cpp)
```

Comment: `#ifdef __cplusplus` is false when you compile fortran, so your definition will be different.

Comment: @stark `myClass_c.h` is being included in `myClass_c.cpp`, so it should be compiled with `g++`

Comment: And is it actually? But I do not think it matters, the gfortran or gcc frontends would call the C++ compiler components, including the respective macros.

Comment: Missing VALUE.  Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249808/why-is-this-attempt-to-pass-a-pointer-from-c-to-fortran-not-working/20252374#20252374 (is there a better duplicate?  this seems to come up frequently enough...)\

Comment: @IanH That's it! Could you provide an answer, so I could accept it?